# Display function result in all items javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to return the function result for all the items using an AJAX function, as it is only showing the data for the latest item. Code is working fine when it only has to show the data for 1 item, however when it has to show it for more than 1, it shows the same one for all of them.

I was testing with alert and it was working fine, it was rendering the data from the image size correctly for each of the items..

I am using this:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
type: "HEAD",
url: imageBase,
success: function(result){
$(".banner-block .title").html(xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Length') + ' bytes');
}
});
```

What is missing so each item displays its particular image size correctly?

Thank you in advance

Comment: what exactly is it that you are trying to acchieve? You are not using the result in the success callback at all. You should probably provide a fiddle or more code.

Comment: Im trying that each item gets the result, if data has to display just for 1 item, then data is displaying correctly, but if there are 3 lets say, then its displaying the same result for the 3 items. Function itself is working fine, but not for more than 1 item.

Comment: But what is it that your are trying to display? What are you getting back from your ajax call? Images? Or json? Or something completely different? You need to provide more details I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes images, when there is more than 1 image, then function display same result for all the images, result is a div with text. Curious thing is that when testing with function alert, it was showing the results correctly for each image.

Comment: so you are calling this multiple times?

Comment: 3 images can show at same time in 1 submit for instance, if I understood you well regarding calling.

Answer (score 0):

Your probelm might be that jquerys `.html()` function replaces. Does it work if you change it to `$(".banner-block .title").append(xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Length') + ' bytes');`

Comment: using .append is showing all results available in each of the items. If I have 3 images displayed, then its showing in each of them the same data from the 3 images.

Comment: You will have to provide some form of fiddle with an example/your problem if you want to get an answer to this...

Comment: this is a bit complicated I guess as it should be displaying images and everything.. isnt any other work around to what I am trying to achieve? I guess the .append gets closer to what Im looking for as its showing all the results, but not individually for each image.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are getting back multiple images in one request. And you want to display the size of each image. IN your success callback you are reading the response size which of course contains the size off all images added together (the whole request) and not the individual ones. Is it possible that this is your problem?

Comment: yes, that is the problem, results are shown correctly, but 1 image needs 1 result, not all of them. At this point is all about matching 1 result with 1 image.

Comment: well what is in the ```result``` variable that is passed to the callback?